# Magento2.3.5 - working very slow & showing error

Tags: error, installation, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1, slow-response

I have installed the `Magento 2.3.5` successfully into my machine locally. After opening the admin page it show below error.

I am using `PHP 7.3` version & installed `Magento on Windows 10`. Also when I try to open admin & homepage its take huge time to load. Please suggest on this.

**Below is the log data:**

```
{"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server","1":"#1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql.php:410]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Db\\Adapter\\Abstract.php:861]\n#3 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('store_website', NULL) called at [generated\\code\\Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql\\Interceptor.php:1636]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql\\Interceptor->quote('store_website') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql.php:1181]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->showTableStatus('store_website', NULL) called at [generated\\code\\Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql\\Interceptor.php:271]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql\\Interceptor->showTableStatus('store_website', NULL) called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql.php:2618]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->isTableExists('store_website', NULL) called at [generated\\code\\Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql\\Interceptor.php:700]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql\\Interceptor->isTableExists('store_website') called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\App\\Config\\Source\\RuntimeConfigSource.php:92]\n#9 Magento\\Store\\App\\Config\\Source\\RuntimeConfigSource->getEntities('store_website', 'code') called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\App\\Config\\Source\\RuntimeConfigSource.php:58]\n#10 Magento\\Store\\App\\Config\\Source\\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Config\\ConfigSourceAggregated.php:40]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('') called at [generated\\code\\Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ConfigSourceAggregated\\Proxy.php:95]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ConfigSourceAggregated\\Proxy->get() called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\App\\Config\\Type\\Scopes.php:63]\n#13 Magento\\Store\\App\\Config\\Type\\Scopes->get('stores\/1') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Config.php:132]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config->get('scopes', 'stores\/1', array()) called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\StoreRepository.php:106]\n#15 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreRepository->getById(1) called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\StoreRepository.php:127]\n#16 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreRepository->getActiveStoreById(1) called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\StoreResolver.php:181]\n#17 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->getDefaultStoreById(1) called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\StoreResolver.php:126]\n#18 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\StoreManager.php:160]\n#19 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager->getStore(NULL) called at [generated\\code\\Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface\\Proxy.php:119]\n#20 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface\\Proxy->getStore(NULL) called at [vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\Resolver\\Store.php:30]\n#21 Magento\\Store\\Model\\Resolver\\Store->getScope(NULL) called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Config\\ScopeCodeResolver.php:49]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL) called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Config.php:69]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config->getValue('admin\/url\/use_cu...', 'stores') called at [vendor\\magento\\module-backend\\App\\Area\\FrontNameResolver.php:123]\n#24 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Area\\FrontNameResolver->isHostBackend() called at [vendor\\magento\\module-backend\\App\\Area\\FrontNameResolver.php:106]\n#25 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Area\\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(true) called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\AreaList.php:76]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\App\\AreaList->getCodeByFrontName('') called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Http.php:111]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\\code\\Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor.php:24]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Bootstrap.php:261]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000003f90d9b70000000079af4522#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/magento2\/","script_name":"\/magento2\/index.php","report_id":"6ba38d89b51e2f5a0b8a3b4274223bf7b2992af8ba79df76f9d117bbd7a7c71c"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is solved. I was having an phpmyadmin access denied issue. I have fixed that & this issue resolved, but still homepage & admin page is working very slow.